# Не удается спарсить все элементы страницы selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Делаю парсер для [сайта](https://www.mvideo.ru/product-list-page?q=%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0) и столкнулся с такой проблемой что получаю не все элементы на странице

```
def parse(driver, addlink):
    driver.get(url + 'product-list-page?q=' + urllib.parse.quote(addlink))
    driver.implicitly_wait(15)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    a = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='price__main-value']")
    print(len(a))
    for i in a:
        ...

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=Options())
driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)

parse(driver, "видеокарта")
```

В инструментах разработчика при поиске нужных элементов так же ищутся не все элементы, но при выборе последующих элементов догружаются

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изменение разрешения экрана меняет количество найденных обьектов.
пробовал явное ожидание, и скролл вниз до конца страницы. Это не дало результатов

Comment: Да, прокруткой проблему не решить, изменением разрешения окна браузера тоже. Как будто читает что его парсят, и он не отображает в доме элементов больше пока не будет какого либо действия, вот не понятно только какого. Возможно физический клик. Но в доме больше их не появилось, только при перелистовании стрелочками как Вы это показали в гифке. Ну... будем думать)))

Comment: Хм, похоже я нашел решение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Интересная ситуация.. Однако есть решение. В самом низу страницы есть выпадающий список "Показать по .." по икспасу: `//*[.='Показать ещё']/../../div[2]/mvid-dropdown/div/div[1]`

Я выбрал из этого списка показать по 12
После чего все 12 элементов отобразились в принте: https://prnt.sc/MhiHlyaPRKqa

Думаю Вам не составит труда прокликать каждую страницу из всех существующих которые там есть, хоть и по 12, за то все.

Код:

```
#Селекторы
test_test = (By.XPATH, "//span[@class='price__main-value']")
test_test_2 = (By.XPATH, "//*[.='Показать ещё']/../../div[2]/mvid-dropdown/div/div[1]")
test_test_2_1 = (By.XPATH, "//*[.='Показать ещё']/../../div[2]/mvid-dropdown/div/div[2]/div[1]")
def parse(self):
    self.element_is_visible(self.locators.test_test_2).click() # Кликаем на элемент выпадающего списка
    self.element_is_visible(self.locators.test_test_2_1).click() # Кликаем на элемент ИЗ выпадающего списка

    c = 0
    a = self.elements_are_visible(self.locators.test_test) # Здесь все цены на видяшки
    for i in a:
        c += 1
        print('element:', c, ' - ', i.text)
```

Comment: Не заметил такой функции, думаю лучше добавлю в ссылку '&showCount=12' чтоб не кликать ничего, но, причину такого поведения элементов хотелось бы узнать. А так мы просто костылем воспользовались.

Comment: Как думаете, есть ли смысл танцевать с XPATH, более точное и сложное выражение сделать?

Comment: Проверил на странице с 12 элементами, так же выводятся не все, от 2 до 10 причем каждый запуск без изменения кода выводит разное кол-во

Comment: Интересно.. У меня сработало. 
По поводу функций, я писал фрейм для удобства. 
Да можно сразу в ссылке указать отображаемое количество элементов. И хотел у Вас спросить, какое Вы разрешение указывали для браузера в опциях? 
У меня стоит `driver.set_window_size(1600, 3000)`, И отрабатывают все 12 цен в прайсе.
Возможно Вы не ставили `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "locator"))` ?

Comment: вы правы WebDriverWait не ставил, а как он должен выглядеть в моем контексте? 
`prices = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='price__main-value']")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until( EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, prices))`
Если честно с неявными ожиданиями не разобрался:)

Comment: `prices = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='price__main-value']") WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until( EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.ID, prices))`
Вот так. А потом в цикле `for i in prices:` выведите i.text как в моем примере, должно сработать